# What is the quickest way to arrange numbers to 3 dimensional array?

Tags: java

I need to arrange numbers of a given size (provided by user at runtime), to 3 dimensional array to represent these numbers in real 3D space.

For example if user enters 7 then I need to create an array of size 2,2,2 and arrange the first 7 numbers given by user into the array starting from position 0,0,0 .

The cube should always be smallest possible for example cube of size 2 can contain 2*2*2 = 8 values. And need a function that can take input numbers and return 3D integer array with values inserted from input array (input[0] will become result[0][0][0] and so on).

```
int input[7] ;
int[][][] result = bestFunction(int[] input) {...}
```

I have implemented with 3 nested for loops by checking each value at a time. 
Is there a better or faster approach to implement it?

Comment: What is exactly the "rule" of creating the array? i.e. You said `input[0]` goes to `result[0][0][0]`, how about `input[1]` `input[2]` and so on?

Comment: it should be sequential, for example if user entered 1,4,3,5,2,3,0
the result should be 0,0,0 = 1, 0,0,1 = 4 , 1,1,0 = 0
1,1,1 = no value

Comment: 3 nested loops should be the fastest. Just keep track of the iteration of the input array so that after the last number from input is put into the result array, use `break;`. If input has n elements, it will be a O(n)

Comment: And an int array cannot have "no value" - all the elements are initialized to 0 so if you don't touch them they will stay 0

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Math.floor(Math.cbrt(val))` to get the dimension size.

I think we can reduce it to level 1 nesting, or using two loops, using a string input for the z-axis values.

```
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
 for(int j = 0;j<size;j++)
    arr[i][j]= Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

where `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` if you're taking in user input.

Comment: I can get the size but 3 nested loops does not look good. For instance after reaching 0,0,1  i need to go next to 0,1,0 etc...

Comment: I will test the above and confirm soon.

Answer (score 0):

Three for loops would be O(n) as long as you break right after the last element of the input is put in.

```
int[][][] func(int[] input) {
    int size = (int) Math.ceil(Math.cbrt(input.length));
    int[][][] result = new int[size][size][size];
    int x = 0;
    loop: for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                result[i][j][k] = input[x++];
                if (x == input.length)
                    break loop; //Finish processing
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```